# sample code for pause action for MPMovie player in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am doing an application using MPMovie Player. In that I want to include code to pause the playing movie. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The MPMoviePlayerViewController class implements the MPMediaPlayback protocol ([see the Apple Developer docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPlayback_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MPMediaPlayback)) so you can use the 'pause' instance method declared here to pause the movie programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

use the function

```
[player pause];
```